# Apply theme to button programmatically

Tags: android, android-appcompat

Is it possible to apply Widget.AppCompat.Button theme to button programmatically?

```
Button button = new Button(context);
button.setText("Button");
```

Currently, I am using custom drawable resource that tries to implement a style like a AppCompat theme, but I think it might be implemented easier.

In the layout it implements like:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeBasedOnAppcompatButton"/>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should use [ContextThemeWrapper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.html), which changes the default theme. Just get a context as you normally would, and use it like below:

```
new Button(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.my_theme));
```

Comment: Thank you! I think my way to implement dynamic layout is wrong. I'll replace it with listview adapter.

Answer (score 1):

In case you need to change the theme progamatically and you are using the support library, you could simply use:

```
TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(getContext(), R.style.AppTheme_TextStyle_ButtonDefault_Whatever);
```

for TextViews and Buttons. There are similar classes for the rest of Views :-)