# Change theme for button programmatically

Tags: android, android-button, android-theme, android-styles

I can able to set theme to button using `android:theme` attribute in xml. Is there any equivalent programmatical code?

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPayment"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Add Payment"
        android:theme="@style/ButtonPeter" // theme..
        />
```

**style.xml**

```
<style name="ButtonPeter" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/fbutton_color_peter_river</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>

    </style>
```

Can I able to set theme dynamically using something like this `btnPayment.setTheme(R.style.ButtonPeter)` ?

I search a lot but all posts are related to set `style` or create dynamic `button` and apply style to it but I dont want to do that .I want to set `theme` to `button`

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confused with `style` and `theme`. From this [document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html), it says: `theme` for the whole activity while `style` is for view.

> A **style** is a collection of properties that specify the look and format for a View or window.
>
> A **theme** is a **style** applied to an entire Activity or application, rather than an individual View.

For this code:

```
android:theme="@style/ButtonPeter" // theme is used but only valid style attributes for button will be applied
```

Hope this help.

Comment: so what is theme attribute find in widget button @TungD.Nguyen?

Comment: so you are suggesting that what I am doing is one type of hack?

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, even if you use a theme, only style attributes related to a button will be applied.

Answer (score 0):

As I mention **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39703575/689723)**, using `TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance` should work :-)

Comment: This works for text-related attributes only, what if I need to change the stroke or background as well?